# ruby method to list self keyword arguments

Tags: ruby

Is there a method that can be called on a method to list the keyword arguments?

What I am looking for is something like

```
self.keyword_arguments
```

For example in the following example i am looking for an array:

```
 [:var1, :var2]
```

```
def test( var1: true, var2: false)
  self.keyword_arguments
end
```

Answer (score 7):

In Ruby, methods are not [first-class objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen). Referring to a method already executes it. That's why we often use symbols to refer to methods via their name. To treat methods in an object-oriented way, Ruby provides the [`Method`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Method.html) class as a wrapper.  Once you obtained a `Method` instance for a method, you can introspect it (or have it introspect itself).

It's a little complicated, but this is how you would approach it:

```
def test( var1: true, var2: false)
  method(__method__)
    .parameters
    .filter_map { |k, v| v if k == :key || k == :keyreq }
end

test
#=> [:var1, :var2]
```

Explanation:

- [`method`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Object.html#method-i-method) looks up a method by its name and returns its `Method` instance
- [`__method__`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Kernel.html#method-i-__method__) returns the current method's name as a symbol, i.e. `:test` in the above code (hard-coding it via `method(:test)` would also work)
- [`parameters`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Method.html#method-i-parameters) returns an array for the arguments as *type* / *name* pairs

For your method, the latter returns `[[:key, :var1], [:key, :var2]]` with `:key` denoting an optional keyword argument (one with default value). `:keyreq` would denote a required keyword argument (one without default value) but you don't have any in your method.

There's also `:keyrest` for arbitrary keyword arguments like `**kwargs`. I've not included `:keyrest` in the output because the `**` argument name is only for "internal" use by the method and not actually used by the caller to pass those extra keyword arguments.

[`filter_map`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-filter_map) then returns the values (i.e. the argument names) for the keys we're interested in.

Comment: There can also be mandatory keyword arguments without a default value. In the `parameters` array, they are denoted with a `:keyreq` type. Also, there can be a list of variable keywords (with e.g. `**kwargs` in the parameters list). Those are denoted as `:keyrest`.